# Informatica infacmd.sh consuming high cpu and load average on linux

Tags: informatica

We are using infacmd.sh to convert  workflow and sessions log bin file to text file. But while converting bin files to text file (5 thread) cpu utilization bump to 85 - 95 % and average load goes more than 15 .

Why infacmd is consuming so much resource to convert bin file to text and how we can reduce such load average and CPU utilization?

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this too earlier in our AIX box. As an improvement, you can -

1. I think you need to reduce amount of logs you are processing.
2. Process only when log size is < some size. There is no use of a very
   huge log file.
3. Do not process all log files. I am sure you can
   exclude some log files

Comment: Thanks koushik for Reply

Comment: For second point -some file keep logging information and file become large for some flows. Any suggestion how we can implement this?